# In Java how can I insert additional data on subscriber profile attributes?

Tags: marketing-cloud, java, fuel-sdk

In Java, using FuelSDK, how can I insert/update and delete a subscriber + insert some additional data on profile attributes? There is something like insert/or update?

Comment: While there's nothing specific on the Code@ site, below may prove useful:
https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/subscribers/subscriber-update.html
 * * 
http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/updating_subscriber_attributes_using_the_update_method/

Comment: Did you find a solution? It could be useful to have an answer on site even if it is posted by yourself